# How to display huge number of images offline without mobile hanging

Tags: android, picasso, image-gallery, android-glide

I am currently working in a project where I have to get huge number of images from Json(back end) and i have to display it to the user . There is no problem for this process if I do it online (with internet connectivity)

My question is, I have to display the same images even offline too, I know that Glide and Picasso can be used in this but I do not know the size of the cache that both have

Which one should i use now in order to make a good gallery in my application 
the thing is, i will get lot of images from back end and i have to display it offline the first time when i sync i will have internet and i will store all the image URL in the local storage

Please guide me how to do this and tell me if there is any other way to perform this

Thank you

Comment: download the images to the file system ,and display them from file system.

Comment: Which one should i use now Glide, Picasso , Fresco suggest me one for displaying thousands of images offline